# problem with Random.nextGaussian()

Tags: java, random

Random.nextGaussian() is supposed to give random no.s with mean 0 and std deviation 1. 
Many no.s it generated are outside range of [-1,+1].
how can i set so that it gives normally distributed random no.s only in the range -1 to 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Gaussian distribution with a mean 0 and standard deviation one means that the average of the distribution is 0 and about 70% of the population lies in the range [-1, 1]. Ignore the numbers that are outside your range -- they form the fringe 16% approx on either side.

Maybe a better solution is to generate a distribution with `mean=0` and `std.dev=0.5`. This will give you a distribution with about 96% of the values in the range [-1, 1].

An even better solution is to work backward as above and use the idea that approx. 99.7% of the values lie in the 3-sigma range: use a `std.dev = 1/3`. That will almost nullify the amount of not-so-useful values that you are getting. When you do get one, omit it.

Of course, if you are working on a math intensive product, all of this bears no value.

Comment: Except, of course, ignoring those numbers means that your random values aren't really normal any more, are they?

Comment: By that definition, any clamping you do on any random number generator is introducing a bias.

Comment: @dirkgently: Absolutely. It's not a normal distribution any more, just one which is "quite like" a normal distribution.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I understand the implications of my suggestion. I'm only saying that S. Lott's observations are right on spot and the OP's question is a paradoxical one. Mais,c'est la vie.

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't the normal distribution include numbers arbitrarily far from the mean, but with increasingly small probabilities?  It might be that your desires (normal and limited to a specific range) are incompatible.

Answer (score 6):

A normal distribution gives a non-zero (but "becoming extremely small") probability of seeing values outside [-1, +1] whatever variance you give - you're just squishing the curve, effectively.

You could use a small variance and then just run the results through a map which cropped anything less than -1 to -1, and anything greater than 1 to 1, but it wouldn't (strictly speaking) be a normal distribution any more.

What do you need this distribution for, out of interest?

Comment: It's not that small.  Close to 30% of the values have to be outside 1 standard deviation.  Something like 5% will lie outside 2 standard deviations.

Comment: The "becoming extremely small" was intended to imply that as you get further away from the mean, the probability of generating the value gets smaller, but still non-zero.

Comment: i am implementing a statistical analysis program. It uses normal distibution.

Comment: BHARATH, If your statistical program requires a normal distribution, why do you not want to use a normal distribution, i.e. why don't you want to let it have its natural range?

Answer (score 2):

Gaussian distribution with your parameters. is has density e^(-x^2/2). In general it is of the form e^(linear(x)+linear(x^2)) which means whatever settings you give it, you have some probability of getting very large and very small numbers.
You are probably looking for some other distribution.

Answer (score 1):

A standard deviation of 1.0 entails that many values will lie outside the [-1,1] range.

If you need to keep within this range, you should use another method, perhaps nextDouble().

Answer (score 1):

This code will display *count* number of random Gaussian numbers to console (10 in a line) and shows you some statistics (lowest, highest and average) afterwards.

If you try it with small *count* number, random numbers will be probably in range [-1.0 ... +1.0] and average can be in range [-0.1 ... +0.1]. However, if *count* is above 10.000, random numbers will fall probably in range [-4.0 ... +4.0] (more improbable numbers can appear on both ends), although average can be in range [-0.001 ... +0.001] (way closer to 0).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 20_000; // Generated random numbers
    double lowest = 0;  // For statistics
    double highest = 0;
    double average = 0;
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        double gaussian = random.nextGaussian();
        average += gaussian;
        lowest = Math.min(gaussian, lowest);
        highest = Math.max(gaussian, highest);
        if (i%10 == 0) { // New line
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.printf("%10.4f", gaussian);
    }
    // Display statistics
    System.out.println("\n\nNumber of generated random values following Gaussian distribution: " + count);
    System.out.printf("\nLowest value:  %10.4f\nHighest value: %10.4f\nAverage:       %10.4f", lowest, highest, (average/count));
}
```