# Random Normal Distribution in Java returns values outside range

Tags: java, random, normal-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem with Random.nextGaussian()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629798/problem-with-random-nextgaussian)

I am working to develop small java application to make random normal distribution and give 50 values.  I use mean = 0.0 and std = 1.0, but the problem I got results out of the bounds there is some values less than 0.0 and else more than 1.0 , can anyone help me?

The following is the code that I used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] list = new double[50];
    double mean = 0.0, std = 1.0;
    Random rng = new Random();

            // to generate 50 values random normal distribution
    for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++) {
      list[i] = mean + std * rng.nextGaussian();
    }

            // to print the generated values from the list
    for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++) 
            {
            System.out.println(list[i]); 
    }


}
```

Comment: Read up some: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/gaussian_distribution_2.shtml "There is theoretically no absoluate minimum and maximum value that can occur in a normal distribution [or nextGaussian] .. In practice with Random.nextGaussian(), there will be some actual minimum/maximum, but not necessarily where we want it to be."

Comment: 0.2776371239704628
-0.5290507951247247
0.43804815423285853
0.20468905235819373
-0.2156071985528327
2.3685922348104165
0.4955808373446519
2.933460293720611

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629798/problem-with-random-nextgaussian?lq=1 (some bug won't let me vote for a duplicate .. anyway, see the answers in there)

Comment: If you think numbers outside the range [0,1] are out of bounds for a standard normal (i.e., mean = 0 and std_dev = 1), you have a fundamental conceptual misunderstanding of the [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). The [red curve in this plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg) is a standard normal, and **most** of the values are outside the range [0,1].

Answer (score 9):

nextGaussian() Returns the next pseudorandom, Gaussian ("normally") distributed double value with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian())

So `std * rng.nextGaussian();` should be `std * (1 + rng.nextGaussian())/2`;

However, the result may not be the gaussian you want, you need to tune the mean value and std with different `a` and `b` in `(a + rng.nextGaussian())/b`

Comment: thanks to answer, and I would ask if there any other way to generate 50 numbers random and make normal distribution for them.

Comment: @user2034269 Just target sigma-3 (or more, sigma-3 would mean 99.7% of the numbers fall in the range; sigma-1 only accounts for 70%) and clamp off the rest? The "clamping" technically alters the distribution, but at some point, who cares? :D

Comment: @user2034269 [nextDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()) should be the right one to use for 50 random numbers. I don't quite understand what do you mean by "make normal distribution for them."

Comment: @KFC That's uniform distribution though :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're interpreting the meaning and purpose of `nextGaussian()` properly.  If you want a number that is in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`, use `nextDouble()` instead.

`nextGaussian()` uses a mean and a standard deviation, ***not a simple number range***. Therefore, it has a theoretically infinite range of return values (within the bounds of `double` at least). Read more about `nextGaussian()` in [this java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29)

Comment: thanks to answer, and I would ask if there any other way to generate 50 numbers random and make normal distribution for them.

Comment: @user2034269 No, not really. Think of the normal distribution like height of all adults in a region. While most people are "about 6 feet" tall, there are outliers. A normal distribution just says "the more away from the mean/average, the less likely it is". See [shortest people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shortest_people) (< 2ft) and [tallest people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_people) (> 8ft). Now, there could be a restriction on a distribution of people heights like: "a human adult can't live if they are < 1ft or > 9ft" and throw out any values that lie outside.

Comment: aha, I got it know .. thanks for your simple example

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the standard deviation with the range of the values. They are not the same thing.

Taken from the [Standard Deviation Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Interpretation_and_application) entry:

> For example, each of the three populations {0, 0, 14, 14}, {0, 6, 8, 14} and {6, 6, 8, 8} has a mean of 7. Their standard deviations are 7, 5, and 1, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

To my understand Javadoc for `nextGaussian()` says:

> Returns the next pseudorandom, Gaussian ("normally") distributed double value with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

It doesn't says the value will be from -1 to 1. Then if you want it to be in that values you can discard outside values or take -1 or 1 when the values are outside.